# Google Map directions using GPS and locations

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, xcode4.2

I'm creating an iPhone app and I need the app to use google maps to give the person directions from where ever they are ,using the phone's gps, to the address that I have listed on the screen.  Is that possible?  I'm a little confused on using the MapView.  Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

Maple: yes its possible to give the directions from your current location to the address entered in the google maps search box.

I am giving you the code to do so.

STEP I - in the header file do this:

```
@interface MapViewController : UIViewController 
{
    IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
    UIButton *button1, *button2;
    IBOutlet UIButton *btnMap;


}
@property(nonatomic,retain)   UIButton *button1, *button2;
@property(nonatomic,retain)IBOutlet UIButton *btnMap;
```

STEP II - in the implementation file perform this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        NSString* searchQuery = @"Bangalore";
        NSString* urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps?q=%@", searchQuery];
        NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
        [webView loadRequest:request];
```

}

STEP III - And last but not the least, in the .xib file do this:

a) add a web view and link it to the files owner.

And don't worry about the current location in GPS enabled phones because Google will automatically detect your current location by using your micro sim card signals to the nearest cell tower.

Just provide your searchQuery and when you click on the get directions tab. google will let you know your current location(MY LOCATION) in the source tab and your searchQuery will be given in the destination.

Hope done for the question:)

Any queries revert to me..

Comment: just to add value.. @maple: you can also make use of MapKit framework.
in map kit you can add annotations and indicate the locations of your choice. Any 1 in need of any basic idea about MapKit please let me know :)

Comment: Yes, that's what I was told to use at first but it wasn't very clear.  Could you elaborate more on the MapKit?

Comment: Also, I tried the code you provided but it seems I'm doing it wrong.  MKMapViewDelegate throws errors for me.  Sorry for being stupid.

Comment: i can provide u d code for rendering maps using MapKit. if interested pls revert..

Comment: Taus, I would love if you could provide that code using MapKit for me.  Thanks!